# Python: Prime number algortihm implementation with square root

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I am trying to solve this problem and despite wrapping my head around it I get stucked over and over and over.

I have a list made of one element [2] and given that and knowing that in order to get a prime number $N$ I have to check that it does not have any prime factor smaller or equal than $\sqrt{N}$, generate all prime numbers between 3 and 100

My code is the following and I will try to explain how I came up with it:

```
prime_numbers = [2]

for k in range(3,100):  # k runs on all numbers to check them
    for i in range (0,len(prime_numbers)): # i is the index of the elements in my list
        if prime_numbers[i] <= sqrt(k):    # first I need to check the sqrt condition
            if k % prime_numbers[i] ==0:     # check that element in list divides k
                k+=1                         # if so k++ and break the cicle
                break
            else:
                i +=1                        # otherwise go to the next elem of the list
        else:                              #if the sqrt condition is not met I have found a prime number    
            value = k
        prime_numbers.append(value)
```

When I run this code it gets into a loop with no exit, and I cannot individuate where the issue is. My best guess would be to correct the most indented else condition, but all the attempts I have done have resulted in failure. Thanks to everyone who is willing to partecipate.

Comment: Neither adjustment of loop control variables within the loop nor modification of the iteration subject within the loop is considered good style - indepently from the used programming language.

Comment: Regardless of style, `i += 1` has no effect when `i` comes from a `range` iterator. The iterator will continue along the same sequence of numbers, regardless of what you do with the variable that each number gets assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
prime_numbers = [2]

for prime_candidate in range(3, 100):
    for known_prime in prime_numbers:
        if known_prime <= sqrt(prime_candidate):
            if prime_candidate % known_prime == 0:
                break
    else:
       prime_numbers.append(prime_candidate)
```

Your problem mainly was, that `i += 1` does not prevent prime_numbers.append to append again.

The for/else can be substituted by a separate flag to trigger all cases without a *break* happening earlier.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get there is:

```
from math import sqrt

prime_numbers=[2]

for k in range(3,101):
    prime=True
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(k))+2):
        if k%i == 0:
            prime=False
            break
    if prime:
            prime_numbers.append(k)

print(prime_numbers)

#Output:
#[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

**Notes:**

- It's `range(3,101)` and not `range(3,100)` if assuming you want to check all numbers *including* 100, otherwise your last number checked will be 99.
- Have a boolean variable `prime`; start by assuming the number is prime (`prime=True`)
- `sqrt(k)` returns a float, while your range expects integers; as such - `int(sqrt(k))`. It's +2 to ensure your range 'to' value is never smaller than your 'from' value of 2.
- `if k%i == 0` (if you have a divisor) the number is not prime (`prime=False`) and `break` the `for` loop to move to the next k
- This could be my "pythonic" by doing a list comprehension, but it may be easier for you to understand in the current format

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who suggested a solution. Meanwhile I came up with one myself.

```
prime_numbers = [2]


for k in range(3,100):
    for i in range (0,len(prime_numbers)):
        if prime_numbers[i] <= sqrt(k):
            if k % prime_numbers[i] ==0:
                k+=1
                break
            else:
                i +=1
        else:
            value = k
    if(value > max(prime_numbers)):
        prime_numbers.append(value)
```